# Como inverter uma coluna em Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Gostaria de saber como inverter o "Nome, Sobrenome, Idade" para "Idade, Nome, Sobrenome" [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código:

```
    import pandas as pd #Importa a biblioteca "Python Data Analysis"

df = pd.read_excel('Pasta1.xlsx') #Lê o arquivo xlsx

df = df.drop('MiddleInitial', axis = 1) #Remove a coluna "MiddleInitial"
df = df.drop('Gender', axis = 1) #Remove a coluna "Gender"
df.rename(columns = {"Age": "Idade", "GivenName": "Nome", "Surname": "Sobrenome"}, inplace = True) #Altera o nome das colunas
df.head() #lê a linha a cima


dfOrdenado = df.sort_values(by = 'Nome', ascending = True) #Ordena a lista
print(dfOrdenado) #Imprime a Lista
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode alterar a ordem das colunas passando as lista com as colunas para o dataframe. Da mesma forma que você pode alterar a ordem, pode também, selecionar menos colunas se houver necessidade.

```
dfOrdenado[['Idade', 'Nome', 'Sobrenome']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Insira o seguinte código:

```
dfOrdenado[['Idade','Nome','Sobrenome']]
```

Ele irá ordenar pelo nome da coluna

Comment: Esse resposta é idêntica a que já havia sido postada antes, não tem nada que você queira acrescentar para deixá-la mais completa ou diferentes? Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4566/3117